# Automapper. Override the default convention

Tags: .net, automapper

Suppose I have the following configuration

```
public class Source
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do is to map Source.EntityId to DestinationId. But just having

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.EntityId))
```

Doesn't solve the problem. It continues mapping Source.Id to Destination.Id. What should I do to override such behavior?

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the contructor I didn't pay enough attention to

```
public class Destination
{
    public Destination(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

So it tried to use constructor for **Id** field initialization. Solved it this way:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForCtorParam("id", opt=> opt.MapFrom(s => s.EntityId));
```